# Automatically copying and organizing data between excel workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a basic table layout with a bunch of columns, each column headed with a specific code of letters (the code isn't important, it's just what the column headers happen to be). In a separate workbook, users input some data which essentially amounts to a number accompanied by a code which corresponds to one of the column headers in the other workbook.

Is there a way I can automate it to take the numbers which are input and copy them into the next available cell in the appropriate column. (e.g. if the user puts in the number 5 into cell A1 with the code ABCD in cell A2, then a 5 gets put into the first empty cell in the ABCD column)

Comment: You really should be using a real database for that.

Comment: If the users are each updating a different workbook, you could use Power Query to merge them all together.

Comment: VBA code? Do you have any sample here?

Comment: Automation needs programming and considering Excel is VBA macro  but  Power Query is also one can be used !!

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

The process looks long and involved. **It's not, it would take seconds each time.** It's just longish to explain. Same idea as when they say a picture's worth a thousand words.

In the rows you want the data brought into, put a formula like the following in each cell. Just use the proper addressing to read the other spreadsheet. I'm going to simply pretend the input data is in cells A1 (value) and B1 (code), and that your table is in columns to the right of them, perhaps starting with column D and the first row's cell in each column has its header. You'll pick the row to paste the formula into and which columns to paste it into.

```
=IF($B$1=D$1,$A$1,"")
```

That's all. Write it in the next row, any of the columns it will go into, adjust the "D1" reference to be that column's first row, press Enter, then copy the cell and paste into all the columns of that row that are used to hold the table's data. So if it uses columns D through AM, write it in any cell in the range Dx:AMx, then paste it into all of them.

Only one column's header will match what is in B1. The value associated (A1) will be written into that column's cell in that row. All the other columns' cells will get a blank written in them (`""`).

Now presumably, there would be more than row of interest in the user's spreadsheet, possibly hundreds or thousands. You would first replace the A1 and B1 cell references with the first row of data's location in the user's spreadsheet. Perhaps that is A6 and B6 on Sheet1. It could even be A6 and B2. Doesn't matter:  you just use whatever the first pair's addresses are. Fill in the next empty row in the master spreadsheet with the formula, after adjusting those addresses, then copy the row and paste down however many rows that there are data rows in the user's spreadsheet. So if he entered six pairs, paste down six rows. If he entered 347 pairs, paste down to fill 347 rows.

When you paste down, be sure to include the first row you filled. That way, when the paste is performed, ALL the rows you entered the formula into will still be highlighted so you can do the next step without error.

Copy the whole set of formulas to the clipboard. Use `Paste | Special | Values` to replace the formulas with their values. That way they are permanent entries in the master spreadsheet. If the user's practice, or yours, is to delete the transferred data from the user's spreadsheet so you don't collect it twice or 30 times, you won't see the data disappear from the master spreadsheet!

That's it for basic use.

You can add sophistication to it as you like. For instance, a quick `IF()` test to check for whether a set of cells are filled in so you don't have to know how many pairs the user added. Just have an idea of how many and paste down extra rows than likely to try to make sure you get all the data without counting rows. And you can make that a lot more sophisticated too. You could add error checking, for perhaps mistakes with the codes (typing errors, so the code entered does not match any column header at all, might be an example) or perhaps errors, or likely errors, in the values entered (maybe it's medical procedure costs and someone entered "1234.561234.56", that kind of error, or millions when it should be thousands, or maybe the amounts are millions but entered as thousands with the ",000" assumed by convention... it could be lots of things).

And sure, one day write some VBA that does the steps for you. After all, "slick" and "sophisticated" can surely be used to describe "I don't work at all, just click a button."

But to do the basics? Just the formula and procedure above.